# Why does Popen.stdout contain only part of output?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, popen, ros

I am running two processes simultaneously in python using the subprocess module:

```
p_topic = subprocess.Popen(['rostopic','echo','/msg/address'], stdout=PIPE)
p_play = subprocess.Popen(['rosbag','play',bagfile_path])
```

These are [ROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System) processes: `p_topic` listens for a `.bag` file to be played and outputs certain information from that `.bag` file to the stdout stream; I want to then access this output using the `p_topic.stdout` object (which behaves as a file).

However, what I find happening is that the `p_topic.stdout` object only contains the first ~1/3 of the output lines it should have - that is, in comparison to running the two commands manually, simultaneously in two shells side by side.

I've tried waiting for many seconds for output to finish, but this doesn't change anything, its approximately the same ratio of lines captured by `p_topic.stdout` each time. Any hints on what this could be would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here's the reading code:

```
#wait for playing to stop
while p_play.poll() == None:
    time.sleep(.1)

time.sleep(X)#wait for some time for the p_topic to finish
p_topic.terminate()

output=[]
for line in p_topic.stdout:
    output.append(line)
```

Note that the value X in time.sleep(X) doesn't make any difference

Comment: does your process terminate? Are you [wait](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)ing for it before doing the last `read`? You should show the reading code

Comment: Also, you may want to use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), it makes things much easier

Comment: Are you sure its not waiting for any input? It does not wait for any input when run from terminal?

Comment: You are making life very hard on yourself, what version of python are you using?

Comment: thanks for feedback, have added readin code. Problem with using check_output is that p_topic needs to run first, then collect output from the p_play process. When I tried p_topic, it halted the program at the first line...

Comment: python 2.7.9 what would be the easy life version of this?! bash script?

Comment: Are you sure your output is pure stdout? maybe some stuff goes to stderr?

Comment: It doesn't wait for any input from terminal no. When I run in terminal 'rostopic echo /blah/blah > file.yaml' that file contains 3x the lines of what's in p_topic.stdout... Also, just checked there's nothing coming through on p_topic.stderr (after adding stderr=PIPE in the Popen call)

Comment: make `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`

Comment: Hi Padraic, doing it this way doesn't increase the number of output lines unfortunately

Comment: well that rules out any output going to stderr,  just out of interest does check_output show all the lines?

Comment: I can't use check_output as it waits for termination no? That's why p_topic is initialised first (get it running in background) then play the .bag, then terminat p_topic. With check_output the program never reaches the p_play command... Maybe time to start all over again with a different method/language :/

Comment: How about starting it with a thread? I have a similar problem with an app of mine, check_output gives all the output but iterating over stdout does not give me all the lines, I was interested to see if you had the same issue, did you try just `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline,"");print(line)`  without polling or terminating just to compare the output?

Comment: Iterating over the lines like you say returns the output as it should be, but then I don't know how to terminate the process (it hangs on the 'for line in iter(...):') - and nothing like 'if line: print; else: break' before this seems to work...

Comment: I have an idea, I will throw something together later when I get back on my comp

Comment: thanks for the help on this. I just tried something else: I changed stdout=PIPE to stdout=open('file.txt', 'wb') in the p_topic process, and the output in the file.txt is perfect (same as in command line). So looks like problem is something to do with the PIPE object, are there size limits on it perhaps? The file.txt file is 190kB by the way

Comment: BAM! there's a 2^15kB size limit on subprocess.PIPE objects!! (that's about 1/3 of 190kB too, so lines up). This blogger had the same problem in 2008: http://thraxil.org/users/anders/posts/2008/03/13/Subprocess-Hanging-PIPE-is-your-enemy/ Looks like I'll be writing to disk then :/

Comment: Yep, I was going to suggest using a  pipe http://www.python-course.eu/pipes.php

Answer (score 1):

By default, when a process's `stdout` is not connected to a terminal, the output is block buffered. When connected to a terminal, it's line buffered. You expect to get complete lines, but you can't unless `rostopic` unbuffers or explicitly line buffers its `stdout` (if it's a C program, you can use `setvbuf` to make this automatic).

The other (possibly overlapping) possibility is that the pipe buffer itself is filling (pipe buffers are usually fairly small), and because you never drain it, `rostopic` fills the pipe buffer and then blocks indefinitely until you kill it, leaving only what managed to fit in the pipe to be drained when you read the process's `stdout`. In that case, you'd need to either spawn a thread to keep the pipe drained from Python, or have your main thread use `select` module components to monitor and drain the pipe (intermingled with polling the other process). The thread is generally easier, though you do need to be careful to avoid thread safety issues.

Comment: Hi, just to confirm, it turned out your second possibility was happening. I found this blog about it: http://thraxil.org/users/anders/posts/2008/03/13/Subprocess-Hanging-PIPE-is-your-enemy/ I'm getting around it by just writing to a local file - although it looks as though there are smarter ways to deal it if the output was really large like you mention, or with defining local FIFO pipes

Comment: That blog is wrong though; using communicate() actually avoids the issue he's talking about (though it's possible some old version of Python had a bug there), because Python implicitly uses select and/or threads to avoid the deadlock there. Problem is, in your case, you want to get partial output (so communicate is not an option).

Answer (score 0):

is it worth trying process communicate/wait? rather than sleep and would that solve your issue?

i have this for general purpose so not sure if you can take this and change it to what you need?

```
    executable_Params = "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}".format(my_Binary, 
                                                       arg1, 
                                                       arg2, 
                                                       arg3, 
                                                       arg4)

    # execute the process
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(executable_Params), 
                               shell=False, 
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE)


    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    ret_code = process.wait()

    if ret_code == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        #get the correct message from my enum method
        error_msg = Process_Error_Codes(ret_code).name
        raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(returncode=ret_code, 
                                            cmd=executable_Params)
```

Comment: Thanks but I think .communicate() waits for the termination of the process? the rostopic process needs to be terminated manually (its stays active until a ctrl-c in the terminal)

Comment: btw this worked for reading stdout/stderr:                    process = subprocess.Popen(my_Params, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                while True:
                    err = process.stderr.read(255)
                    print stdo
                    if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
                        break
                    if out != '':
                        proc_err_flag = 1
                        sys.stdout.write(out)
                        sys.stdout.flush()